# Left limit as adjunction

Tags: category-theory

I am reading [Galois theory for schemes](https://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf) by Lenstra. In Exercise 3.1, he defines the notion of a left limit:

> A left limit of a $D$-diagram $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$ is an object $\varprojlim A$ such that $$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(-,\varprojlim A)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^D}(\Gamma(-),A)$$ as functors.

This is the formulation in terms of adjoint functors of the usual definition:

We say an object $L$ together with $f\colon \Gamma(L)\to A$ is a left limit of $A$ if: for every object $K$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and every $g\colon \Gamma(K)\to A$ there is a unique $\beta\colon K\to L$ such that $g=f\Gamma(\beta)$.

I see that these are equivalent: if $K$ is an object of $\mathcal{C}$ and $g\colon \Gamma(K)\to A$ then using the bijection we can find a unique $\beta\colon K\to L$. The condition $g=\Gamma(\beta)f$ follows from  following the commutative diagram. In the adjoint formulation, the map $\Gamma(L)\to A$ is omitted. I suppose that it is implicitly defined to be the image of $\operatorname{id}_L$ under the unit of the adjunction. Shouldn't this be part of the definition ??

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Hom_{C}(L,L) @>{\sim}>> Hom_{C^D}(\Gamma(L),A);\\
@VV{-\circ\beta}V @VV{-\circ\Gamma(\beta)}V \\
Hom_{C}(K,L) @>{\sim}>> Hom_{C^D}(\Gamma(K),A);
\end{CD}$$

If this is true then if we trace $id_{L}$ through the diagram we get $f\Gamma(\beta)=g$.

For instance, in the case that $A$ is the diagram with two vertices and no edges, in which case the limit is the product, $f$ gives the pair of projections onto the coordinates.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you would suggest to change in the definition. If there is an isomorphism of functors $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(-,\varprojlim A)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^D}(\Gamma(-),A)$, then in particular there is a bijection $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(\varprojlim A,\varprojlim A)\simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^D}(\Gamma(\varprojlim A),A)$, and thus the identity of $\varprojlim A$ defines a morphism $f: \Gamma(\varprojlim A)\to A$. I don't think there is a need to add anything special about $f$ in this definition.